# One word to denote natural items found on ground

Tags: single-word-requests

Does there exist one word or one term to denote natural items found on the ground such as trees, grass, rocks etc.?

A word that encompasses both inanimate as well as animate objects but that is not man-made.

Comment: *Geography?* That's just geology with trees, as Terry Pratchett says.

Comment: I don't think there's likely to be anything more specific than "natural items". Collectively, *trees* and *grass* are in the general category ***flora*** (as opposed to ***fauna*** for *animals*). But not many people would call an individual plant or animal an "object", and to a first approximation all other "natural things" are essentially just ***rocks*** (or stones, pebbles, etc.).

Comment: **naturalia** but it's not English.

Comment: What about scenery? Would that qualify?

Comment: How about _topography_, in this sense (from Merriam Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary): "the physical or natural features of an object or entity and their structural relationships"—where the object or entity is the earth?

Comment: It might or might not matter that *Some things are on the ground, some are in the ground.* Some things are found on the ground, such that one may pick them up (even if you need a steamshovel); other things are rooted in the ground (trees, grass, mineral outcroppings) such that they cannot be picked up, but they need to be uprooted or dug up.

Comment: _Formation_ is a broader term but you can use in the right context. Also, it is emphasized as _natural formation_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aground = on the ground (adjective) (Am.Heritage [definition](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=aground)) but that probably doesn't readily go for *rooted* items.

surface-found items = naturally mean on the surface (of the earth)

But there may be a problem in that you are asking to describe two categories of things: on the ground and rooted in the ground

Answer (score 1):

**"nature"** Simple as that. I don't think there is a better word.

> "nature" (noun) the physical world and everything in it (such as plants, animals, mountains, oceans, stars, etc.) that is not made by people.

Comment: The object has to be connected to the ground, so it should exclude stars etc..

Answer (score 0):

**Detritus**--gravel, sand, silt or other material produced by erosion; organic matter produced by the decomposition of organisms.

Comment: This word mainly refers to waste-type of objects. Diamonds, gemstones, pearls etc. would be excluded from this word.